# jQuery Show/Hide cookie button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a simple jQuery show/hide script that is cookie based.  If anyone can provide me with a script, that would be great.

Below is the guide on what I am trying to achieve.

- if cookie is not set

  - Set all div's with a class of admin as visible
  - Display hide link
- If cookie is set

  - Hide div's with admin class
  - Display Show link

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use an if/then statement based on the cookie value by using the [jquery-cookie plugin.](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) as such:

```
$.cookie("foo")
```